# DLookup statement from SQL to VBA

Tags: ms-access-2010

Please help to solve this statement: "Too few parameters expected 1".

The problem is on the

`If(IsNull([tblMaintWO]![Technian1]),'', DLookup('Initial', tblEmployees, 'EmpID=' & [tblMaintWO]![Technian1])) AS TechnianA`

I can't put the double quotes in the statement or it will show a red sentence and raise the error.

```
strSQL = "SELECT tblMaintWO.MWONo, tblMaintWO.TaskOpenDate, tblMaintWO.MTRStation, tblMaintWO.Task, tblMaintWO.RequestedPriority, tblMaintWO.WorkOrderStatus, tblMaintWO.Technian1, "
strSQL = strSQL & "IIf([CMFollowUp] = True, 'CM', IIf([PreventiveMaint] = True, 'PM', IIf([EIVO] = True, 'EI/VO', 'Other'))) AS TaskType, "
strSQL = strSQL & "IIf(IsNull([tblMaintWO]![Technian1]),'', DLookup('Initial', tblEmployees, 'EmpID=' & [tblMaintWO]![Technian1])) AS TechnianA "
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM tblMaintWO, tblEmployees;"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT tblMaintWO.MWONo, tblMaintWO.TaskOpenDate, tblMaintWO.MTRStation, tblMaintWO.Task, tblMaintWO.RequestedPriority, tblMaintWO.WorkOrderStatus, tblMaintWO.Technian1, "
strSQL = strSQL & "IIf([CMFollowUp] = True, 'CM', IIf([PreventiveMaint] = True, 'PM', IIf([EIVO] = True, 'EI/VO', 'Other'))) AS TaskType, "
strSQL = strSQL & "IIf(IsNull([tblMaintWO]![Technian1]),'', DLookup('Initial', 'tblEmployees', 'EmpID=' & [tblMaintWO]![Technian1] & '')) AS TechnianA "
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM tblMaintWO, tblEmployees;"
```